# Skip row depending on value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe obtained by scraping a website:
[image]

As you can see it needs to be adjusted, in particular where the column ID has the "Live" value i need to shift 2 columns to get the entire df aligned properly.

I tried this with my df being db2

```
rows_to_shift = db2[db2['Min'] == 'Live']

db2.loc[rows_to_shift] = db2.loc[rows_to_shift].shift(2,axis=1)
```

But i got "ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key"...before i used iloc instead but this error came in "IndexError: DataFrame indexer is not allowed for .iloc
Consider using .loc for automatic alignment." and so tried loc

Comment: Probably i wasn't clear, i need to shift two positions where the value is "Live" but need to keep the other row where value are properly aligned (my screen was an example, the not aligned row are randomly placed into the df). With both the solutions below rows where columns Min is not "Live" are deleted

Comment: Thanks to both , now it works, probably ii was doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#mask for filtering
mask = db2['Min'] == 'Live'
#columns for shift - all without first ID
c = db2.columns[1:]
#shift columns
db2.loc[mask, c] = db2.loc[mask, c].shift(2, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the columns for shift as `.loc` takes 2 arguments in this case - both rows (`rows_to_shift` and columns (`db2.columns[2:]`).

You can try something like this:

```
db2.loc[db2['Min'] == 'Live', db2.columns[2:]] = db2.loc[db2['Min'] == 'Live', db2.columns[2:]].shift(2, axis=1)
```